# Making Line ActionScript using lineTo

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, line

I'm extremely new to flash programming, and suddenly my teacher give me assignment to make a flash about mirror reflection line.

Here is my as code to draw a simple line after following some tutorial online.

```
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("holder",1);
holder.clear();
holder.lineStyle(1,0,100);
holder.moveTo(benda._x, benda._y);
holder.lineTo(289.95, 199.9);
```

Now i got a problem, "benda" is a motion tween object, when i test it, the as created line don't move, but "benda" move. what should i do to make it move ?

Thanks, sorry for my bad english

Comment: If you only run the code once, you only get a "snapshot" of the position of the object. Care to elaborate on exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zeulb,

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, or how much you already know about drawing in Flash.

But, here's a breakdown of what your current code is doing...

```
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("holder",1);
```

This line will create a new movie clip named "holder" in your movie, at level 1.

```
holder.clear();
```

This line will clear the "drawing surface" in your "holder" movie clip. However, since you've JUST created "holder", it's already empty/clear. So, this line technically isn't necessary, and won't do anything.

```
holder.lineStyle(1,0,100);
```

This line sets the drawing style in your "holder" movie clip. The first parameter is the thickness of the line (1 pixel). The second parameter is the color ("0" = black). The third parameter is the alpha (transparency) of the line ("100" = fully opaque). So - long story short - the style is a 1-pixel thick black line.

```
holder.moveTo(benda._x, benda._y);
```

This line tells Flash to "move" the invisible starting point of your drawing to these coordinates:
    x: the current X coordinate of "benda" (whatever that is...)
    y: the current Y coordinate of "benda"

In other words - from the snippet of code you posted, it's not possible to tell what "benda" is. But, I'm guessing it's another movie clip you created elsewhere. So - long story short - you're telling Flash to begin a line in your "holder" movie clip that starts at the same coordinates as "benda".

```
holder.lineTo(289.95, 199.9);
```

This line of code says, "from the starting point you just set with the previous "moveTo" command, draw a line to "289.95,199.9".

So - ultimately, your code will create a movie clip named "holder", then in that clip's drawing surface, draw a line from (benda._x, benda._y) to (289.95, 199.9).

With a little more clarification, I'd be happy to help you with whatever you're trying to do.